# H2 Database - Alter multiple databases

Tags: alter-table, h2

I need to alter a table in H2 db. But we have millions of databases with the same same table. What may be the feasible way to alter such databases?

Comment: Millions, really?

Answer (score 0):

## Database migration

[*Database migration*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) or *schema migration* are the evolving terms for the process of managing and deploying changes to the structure of your database.

The idea is that you never make ad-hoc changes to your database. Instead, you make a disciplined practice of accumulating scripts (SQL, XML, etc.), and optionally executable code, to implement each stage of your database’s evolution: adding tables, adding columns, altering columns, etc.

Tools such as [Flyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) and [Liquibase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase) automate the process of managing and executing your collection of scripts and optional code. If you deploy such a tool along with your database or app, the tool can automatically detect which scripts and/or executables need to be run to update the currently-used database to the latest and greatest.